# Importing a Mathematica Matrix

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to import a very large matrix file to a variable using the code below.  The matrix is of the form {{A,B,C},{D,E,D},{G,F,A}}

```
inputseq2s = Import[ "C:\Users\jdd0758\Desktop\WaveformsOnly.txt","Data"]
```

However when I import it like this, it is not read as if it was entered as:

```
inputseq2s = {{A,B,C},{D,E,D},{G,F,A}}
```

Extra commas are added to the input and it will not work in my algorithm.  How can I make this work properly?

Comment: Could you add the first few lines of the data to the question? Is all the data in one line?

Comment: I am not able to add a file after the original submission is there any other way to get it to you?

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1825675).